# My python3 manage.py makemigrations or python manage.py makemigrations is erroring

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I am trying to run th migration prompt in Django but it isn't working.

This is the error:

```
@user: django_angular_auth_api % python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/django-angular-auth/django_angular_auth_api/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/user/django-angular-auth/django_angular_auth_api/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 106, in wrapper
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 137, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 305, in build_graph
    self.graph.ensure_not_cyclic()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 284, in ensure_not_cyclic
    raise CircularDependencyError(
django.db.migrations.exceptions.CircularDependencyError: users.0001_initial
```

I added in a dependency and did everything possible to try and fix it. I wiped and redid db, and most other things I found online.

Answer (score 0):

Your migration files are corrupted.

There is a migration that depends on `users.0001_initial` and `users.0001_initial` depends on something that depends on that migration.

If you don't care about deleting all your data, you can remove all migrations and rebuild them.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: In each app, go to migrations/ folder and delete its content except __init__.py and then run python manage.py makemigrations

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby Better to edit your post with essential information than to leave it as a comment